# How to add group chat functionality to AppRTC

Tags: apprtc

I have downloaded the source code of AppRTC android app and able to run the app using the Android Studio.

To start communicating with each other, one needs to join a room by entering it name. By default, AppRTC allows only two participants to join a room. When third participant tries to join a room, it gives error " Room is full".

I want to provide a Group chat functionality to this app, so that more than 2 participants can join same room.

I'm unable to identify the exact class or method where to do changes to make this work. I need help in doing this.

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that if you're using the default server, that Google changed it to only allow 2 people to be in any one room. 
I believe that the only way to get around this is to deploy your own version on your own server and change the settings to allow more than 2 "occupants" of a chat/video room

Steve